# I get "_free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);" I'm trying to work on stacks and queues

Tags: c++, stack, queue, allocation

I'm working on visual studio. 
My project is: Write a stack and queue test driver. A test driver is a program created to
test functions that are to be placed in a library. Its primary purpose is to
completely test functions therefore it has no application use. You will use two
stacks and two queues in the program, as described below.

a. inS – input stack: used to store all user input

b. inQ – input queue: used to store all user input

c. outS – output stack: used to store data deleted from inQ

d. outQ – output queue: used to store data deleted from inS

And I need to do the following in main: 
I – insert, D – delete, C – display the number of elements in the two
stacks and two queues, T – display the elements at the top of the two stacks, F –
display the elements at the front of the two queues, R – display the elements at
the end of the two queues

Like this, I'm trying to work on queues and stacks. But the below is shown.

```
//
// delete_scalar.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete.
//
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>
#include <vcstartup_internal.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// delete() Fallback Ordering
//
// +-------------+
// |delete_scalar<----+-----------------------+
// +--^----------+    |                       |
//    |               |                       |
// +--+---------+  +--+---------------+  +----+----------------+
// |delete_array|  |delete_scalar_size|  |delete_scalar_nothrow|
// +--^----^----+  +------------------+  +---------------------+
//    |    |
//    |    +-------------------+
//    |                        |
// +--+--------------+  +------+-------------+
// |delete_array_size|  |delete_array_nothrow|
// +-----------------+  +--------------------+

_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

The below is the whole code(two .h files and one .cpp files).
1. stackADT.h

```
    /**~*~*
       Stack template
    *~**/
    #ifndef STACK_ADT_H
        #define STACK_ADT_H
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    // Structure for the stach nodes
    struct StackNode
    {
        T value;          // Value in the node
        StackNode *next;  // Pointer to next node
    };

    StackNode *top;     // Pointer to the stack top
    int count;

public:
    //Constructor
    Stack() { top = NULL; count = 0; }

    // Destructor
    ~Stack();

    // Stack operations
    bool push(T);
    bool pop(T &);
    bool isEmpty();
    int getCount();
    bool getTop(T &);
};

/**~*~*
   Destructor
*~**/
template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    StackNode *currNode, *nextNode;

    // Position nodePtr at the top of the stack.
    currNode = top;

    // Traverse the list deleting each node.
    while (currNode) //while (currNode != NULL)
    {
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        delete currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }    
}

/**~*~*
  Member function push pushes the argument onto
  the stack.
*~**/
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::push(T item)
{
    StackNode *newNode; // Pointer to a new node

    // Allocate a new node and store num there.
    newNode = new StackNode;
    if (!newNode)
        return false;
    newNode->value = item;

    // Update links and counter
    newNode->next = top;
    top = newNode;
    count++;

    return true;
}

/**~*~*
  Member function pop pops the value at the top
  of the stack off, and copies it into the variable
  passed as an argument.
*~**/
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::pop(T &item)
{
    StackNode *temp; // Temporary pointer

    // empty stack
    if (count == 0)
        return false;

    // pop value off top of stack
    item = top->value;
    temp = top->next;
    delete top;
    top = temp;
    count--;

    return true;
}

/**~*~*
  Member function isEmpty returns true if the stack
  is empty, or false otherwise.
*~**/
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return count == 0;
}

/**~*~*
  Member function getCount returns
  the number of elements in the stack
*~**/
template <class T>
int Stack<T>::getCount()
{
    return count;
}

/**~*~*
  Member function getTop copies the value at the top
  of the stack into the variable passed as an argument.
*~**/
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::getTop(T &item)
{
    if (top == NULL)
        return false;

    item = top->value;

    return true;
}


#endif
```

2. QueueADT.h

   ```
   #ifndef DYNAMICQUEUE_H
   #define DYNAMICQUEUE_H
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   template <class T>
   class Queue
   {
   private:
       // Structure for the queue nodes
   struct QueueNode
   {
       T value;          // Value in the node
       QueueNode *next;  // Pointer to next node
   };

   QueueNode *front;    // Pointer to the queue front
   QueueNode *rear;     // Pointer to the queue rear
   int count;

   public:
   //Constructor
   Queue() { front = rear = NULL; count = 0; }

   // Destructor
   ~Queue();

   // Queue operations
   bool enqueue(T);
   bool dequeue(T &);
   bool isEmpty();
   int  getCount();
   bool queueFront(T &);
   bool queueRear(T &);
   };

   /**~*~*
      Destructor
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   Queue<T>::~Queue()
   {
       QueueNode *currNode, *nextNode;

       // Position nodePtr at the top of the stack.
       currNode = front;

       // Traverse the list deleting each node.
       while (currNode) //while (currNode != NULL)
       {
           nextNode = currNode->next;
           delete currNode;
           currNode = nextNode;
       }
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function getCount returns
     the number of elements in the queue
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   int Queue<T>::getCount()
   {
       return count;
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function isEmpty returns true if the stack
     is empty, or false otherwise.
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   bool Queue<T>::isEmpty()
   {
       return count == 0;
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function enqueue inserts the argument into
     the queue.
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   bool Queue<T>::enqueue(T item)
   {
       QueueNode *newNode; // Pointer to a new node

        // Allocate a new node and store num there.
       newNode = new QueueNode;
       if (!newNode)
           return false;
       newNode->value = item;

       // Update links and counter
       newNode->next = NULL;

       if (front == NULL)        // insert to an empty queue
           front = newNode;
       else
           rear->next = newNode;

       count++;
       rear = newNode;

       return true;
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function dequeue deletes the value at the front
     of the queue, and copies it into the variable
     passed as an argument.
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   bool Queue<T>::dequeue(T &item)
   {
       QueueNode *pDel; // Temporary pointer

       // empty queue
       if (count == 0)
           return false;

       // delete the value at the front of the queue
       item = front->value;
       pDel = front;

       if (count == 1)
           rear = NULL;
       front = front->next;

       count--;
       delete pDel;

       return true;
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function queueFront copies the value at the front
     of the queue into the variable passed as an argument.
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   bool Queue<T>::queueFront(T &item)
   {
       if (front == NULL)
           return false;

       item = front->value;

       return true;
   }

   /**~*~*
     Member function queueRear copies the value at the rear
     of the queue into the variable passed as an argument.
   *~**/
   template <class T>
   bool Queue<T>::queueRear(T &item)
   {
       if (rear == NULL)
           return false;

   item = rear->value;
   return false;
   }

   #endif
   ```

3.Main.cpp

```
/**
CIS 22C: Homework 3

Build and process a sorted circularly doubly-linked list of Toy objects.
The list is sorted in ascending order by toy ID.
The toy ID is a unique key.

IDE: Visual Studio
Written By: Younseo Ryu
Changed By:

**/
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>  // toupper function
#include "StackADT.h"
#include "QueueADT.h"
using namespace std;

void printWelcome();
void insertSQ(Stack<double> &, Queue<double> &);
void deleteSQ(Stack<double> &, Stack<double> &, Queue<double> &, Queue<double> &);
void displayCountSQ(Stack<double>, Stack<double>, Queue<double>, Queue<double>);
void displayTopS(Stack<double>, Stack<double>);
void displayEndQ(Queue<double>, Queue<double>);



int main()
{
    Stack<double> inS; Stack<double> outS;
    Queue<double> inQ; Queue<double> outQ;
    printWelcome();

    insertSQ(inS, inQ);
    insertSQ(inS, inQ);
    insertSQ(inS, inQ);
    deleteSQ(inS, outS, inQ, outQ);


    displayCountSQ(inS, outS, inQ, outQ);
    displayTopS(inS, outS);
    displayEndQ(inQ, outQ);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/**********************
This function prints a welcome message and a description of the program
*********************/
void printWelcome()
{
    cout << "\n\n\t\t *~~*~~* WELCOME *~~*~~*\n\n"
        << "\tTo the Stack and Queue Program!\n\n"
        << "\t\tThis program will: \n"
        << "\t\t -I: Insert \n"
        << "\t\t -D: Delete  \n"
        << "\t\t -C: Display the number of elements in the two stacks and two queues \n"
        << "\t\t -T: Display the elements at the top of the two stakcs \n"
        << "\t\t -F: disdisplay the elements at the front of the two queues \n"
        << "\t\t -R: display the elements at the end of the two queues \n"
        << "\t\t -Q: to quit the program. \n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t \n\n";
}

void insertSQ(Stack<double> &stack, Queue<double> &queue)
{
    double item;
    cout << "enter a number to insert it in inS and inQ: ";
    cin >> item; 
    stack.push(item);
    queue.enqueue(item);
}

void deleteSQ(Stack<double> &inS, Stack<double> &outS, Queue<double> &inQ, Queue<double> &outQ)
{
    double item;
    cout << "the top stack element is popped.\n";
    inS.pop(item);
    outS.push(item);
    inQ.dequeue(item);
    outQ.enqueue(item);
}

void displayCountSQ(Stack<double> inS, Stack<double> outS, Queue<double> inQ, Queue<double> outQ)
{
    cout << "there are " << inS.getCount() << " elements in the stack inS\n"
         << "there are " << outS.getCount() << " elements in the stack outS\n"
         << "there are " << inQ.getCount() << " elements in the queue inQ\n"
         << "there are " << outQ.getCount() << " elements in the queue outQ\n";
}

void displayTopS(Stack<double> inS, Stack<double> outS)
{
    double item;
    if (inS.getTop(item))
        cout << "the top element in the stack inS is the following: " << item << "\n";
    else
        cout << "the stack inS is empty. so there's no top element in inS.\n";

    if(outS.getTop(item))
        cout << "the top element in the stack outS is the following: " << item << "\n";
    else
        cout << "the stack outS is empty. so there's no top element in inS.\n";
}

void displayEndQ(Queue<double> inQ, Queue<double> outQ)
{
    double item;

    if (inQ.queueFront(item))
        cout << "the front element of the queue inQ is: " << item <<"\n";
    else cout << "no front element found in inQ\n";

    if (inQ.queueRear(item))
        cout << "the rear element of the queue inQ is: " << item << "\n";
    else cout << "no rear element found in inQ\n";

    if (outQ.queueFront(item))
        cout << "the front element of the queue inQ is: " << item << "\n";
    else cout << "no front element found in inQ\n";

    if (outQ.queueRear(item))
        cout << "the rear element of the queue inQ is: " << item << "\n";
    else cout << "no rear element found in inQ\n";
}
```

Comment: TL;DR.  All I needed to see was this: `void displayCountSQ(Stack<double> inS, Stack<double> outS, Queue<double> inQ, Queue<double> outQ)
` and automatically knew this was doomed for failure.  You failed to adhere to the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  You are passing these objects by value, which means they need to have correct copy semantics, and they do not.  All of these classes need copy constructors and assignment operators.